# CMAKE could not find JAVA

Tags: java, visual-studio, cmake, sumo

I am trying to use CMake to compile the source code for SUMO in windows system using visual studio 2017. However, it keeps giving me an error of not finding JAVA. I just install the jdk-14.0.1 and added it as JAVA_HOME path but it doesn't resolve the problem. I may have an old version of JAVA installed and CMake could be trying to use it. How may I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Error Code

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:140 (message):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:143

  when parsing string

    Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "1.8.0_202"

  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)

  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
  -agentpath:"c:\windows\fireeye\javaagentdll_00.dll")

  Invalid character escape '\w'.        C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake   140
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When adding an environment variable (e.g. JAVA_HOME) to the PATH it is often necessary to reopen the console windows, the explorer and the Visual Studio instance for the change to take effect. You might also logout and login again.

Comment: @vre Thanks! Restarting did the trick!